# How can I find the basis of a subspace in $R^n$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Linear algebra test tomorrow. How can I find the basis of a vectorial subspace of $R^n$?
The exam question that made me ask this was:

> Find the basis of the subspace of $R^3$ generated by $S=\{(-1, 2, 5), (3, 0, 3), (5, 1, 8)\}$

Comment: Can you determine whether the set is linearly dependent?

Comment: Welcome to MSE, and good job with the MathJax! Please explain what you have tried, learned about spanning sets, etc.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you very much. I know that the vectors have to be linearly independent and they have to span $R^n$. The problem is that I don't get how should I tackle the problem. Lately we've been short on time and had to go over the topics way too fast to finish the course.

Comment: "And they have to span $R^n$"  No, they don't.  They merely have to span the subspace of $R^n$ that you are interested in showing they are a basis for (*which they trivially do*).

Comment: As for the phrasing of the question... "Find **THE** basis of the subspace..." that is bad wording.  There are in almost every case infinitely many valid bases for any subspace (*the exceptions being when it is a finite vector space over a finite field or when the subspace in question is zero-dimensional*).  As for a method of finding *a* basis for the subspace generated by $\{u_1,u_2,u_3,\dots,u_k\}$, iteratively go through the list, and removing unnecessary vectors which are linearly dependent on those vectors which precede it.  What remains is a maximal linearly independent set, a basis.

Comment: So I did the reduction on the matrix and I got 
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}

$$
What can I conclude from that?

Comment: For example, Find the basis of the space generated by $\{(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(0,0),(1,0)\}$, We first see that the first $(0,0)$ is unnecessary so we discard it.  We then see $(1,1)$ is worthwhile to keep.  We then compare it to $(2,2)$ and see that these are linearly dependent, so we discard $(2,2)$.  We again discard $(0,0)$ since it is again linearly dependent, and then we keep $(1,0)$ since it is linearly independent to $(1,1)$.  Leaving us with $\{(1,1),(1,0)\}$.  We could have just as well called the basis $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ via other methods, but it is unnecessary.

Comment: The conclusion from your reduction is that $(1,0,1),(0,1,3)$ act as a basis.  But, you could just as easily have called it $(-1,2,5),(3,0,3)$ and been just as correct.

Comment: @JMoravitz just one more question, is there a way to prove that they are a basis after getting them? How can I do so?

Comment: By showing that the proposed basis is indeed linearly independent, and that if you take the proposed basis and include a copy (*potentially an additional copy*) of any one of the vectors from the generating set that it becomes linearly dependent.

Comment: @JMoravitz a maybe stupid question: Can I prove it by using the linear combination formula?
$v = c_1(v_1) + c_2(v_2) + ... + c_n(v_n)$

Comment: Yes, or from a row reduction argument, but from the fact that the vectors you got were *from* row reduction of the original vectors in the first place, you already know that they will span the same set from theorem.  If you use my method, then you know they will span the same set because they *are* the same set (*minus the unnecessary vectors*).  Checking they span the same set is usually only done if you want to ask something like "Prove $\{a,b,c\}$ is a basis for the space generated by as $\{u,v,w,x\}$" where you don't know how $a,b,c$ were produced.

Comment: @JMoravitz to prove it I substitute them in the formula and equate them to $(0, 0, 0)$, then I in fact got $c_1 = c_2 = 0$ is that the right procedure?

Answer (score 0):

That's a set of 3 vectors so any space spanned by has dimension less than or equal to 3.  It will have dimension 3 if and only if all three vectors are *independent*.  It that case the three given vectors are a basis.  It will have dimension 2 if and only if two of the vectors are independent but the third is a linear combination of those two vectors.  In that case the two independent vectors form a basis.  It will have dimension three if only all vectors are multiples of one.  In that case any one of the three is a basis by itself.

Comment: Perhaps you know how to do "Gaussian reduction" to determine these things about dependence.

Answer (score 0):

Write the vectors as rows of a matrix and perform [row reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). The nonzero rows will form a basis of the subspace generated by the original nows.

In your example, the reduced matrix is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\     0 & 1 & 3 \\     0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The two nonzero rows are linearly independent because in a linear combination $a_1 r_1 + a_2 r_2 =0$, we must have $a_1=0$ because the first coordinate of $r_2$ is zero. Likewise, $a_2=0$ because the second coordinate of $r_1$ is zero.

Comment: I did already and got this matrix:
\begin{matrix}     1 & 0 & 1 \\     0 & 1 & 3 \\     0 & 0 & 0 \\     \end{matrix}
Does that means that $(1, 0, 1)$ and $(0, 1, 3)$ are the basis of the subspace?

Comment: @Recondito, yes, exactly. You may add this info to your question.

Comment: Is there a way I can  prove it that they are basis? How can I do so?

Comment: @Recondito, just prove that they are linearly independent. This is clear because the rows are reduced.

Comment: @lhf look, this is my biggest doubt on this topic. How do I prove they are linearly independent?
Do I have to equate them to 0 in the linear combination formula and solve the system?

Answer (score 0):

A *basis* of a subspace is a set of vectors that both spans the entire subspace and is linearly independent.

Given a set of vectors $S=\{(-1,2,5),(3,0,3),(5,1,8)\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$

Lets check which vectors are linearly independent and spans S. We want to find $x,y,z$ such that :

$x(-1,2,5)+y(3,0,3)+z(5,1,8)=0$, by doing so, we get a system of equations on $x,y,z$.

As a matrix, ths system of equation would look like this :

$
 \begin{gather}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   -1&3&5\\2&0&1\\5&3&8 
   \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
   x\\y\\z 
   \end{bmatrix}=0
\end{gather}
$

We can simplify using row reduction without changing the span of the three vectors, and we get :

$
  \begin{bmatrix}
   1&0&0.5\\0&1&\frac {11}{6} \\0&0&0 
   \end{bmatrix}
$

Which translates into:

$x+0.5z=0$

$y+\frac {11} {6}z=0$

$0=0$

since $z$ is arbitrary (We have no constraints on $z$), we can pick $z=1$ and get :

$\frac {1}{2}(-1,2,5)+\frac {11}{6}(3,0,3)=(5,1,8)$

So the third vector is a linear combination of the first two, meaning the span of the two first vectors is the same span of S.
In addition, the first two vectors are linearly independent.
So $E=\{(-1,2,5),(3,0,3)\}$ is a basis of S.

A more simple approach would be to arrange the given vectors as rows in a matrix, and find the reduced row form. Since the span does not change, we can take the non-zero rows as our basis vectors.